# Count vowels and consonants in an array

Tags: function, t-sql, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying to write a `function` which will return number of vowels
and consonants. Using the `IF` statement function will successfully
compile, however when I call it in the select it shows the message :

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'MAMAMIA' to
> data type int."`

I tried with the `CASE` statement, but there are too many syntax
errors and i think it is not the best method of solving the problem
using CASE ...

```sql
 CREATE FUNCTION VOW_CONS(@ARRAY VARCHAR(20))
 RETURNS INT
 BEGIN

 DECLARE @COUNTT INT;
 DECLARE @COUNTT1 INT; 
 
 SET @COUNTT=0;
 SET @COUNTT1=0;

 WHILE (@ARRAY!=0)
 BEGIN
  IF(@ARRAY LIKE '[aeiouAEIOU]%') 
 
 SET @COUNTT=@COUNTT+1 

 ELSE SET @COUNTT1=@COUNTT1+1

/*
 DECLARE @C INT; 
SET @C=(CASE @SIR WHEN 'A' THEN  @COUNTT=@COUNTT+1; 
        WHEN 'E' THEN  @COUNTT=@COUNTT+1
        WHEN 'I' THEN  @COUNTT=@COUNTT+1
        WHEN 'O' THEN  @COUNTT=@COUNTT+1 
        WHEN 'U' THEN  @COUNTT=@COUNTT+1 
        WHEN 'A' THEN  @COUNTT=@COUNTT+1
        WHEN ' ' THEN ' '
   ELSE  @COUNTT1=@COUNTT1+1
   END) 
*/

 END

  RETURN @COUNTT;

END

SELECT DBO.VOW_CONS('MAMAMIA')
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us; we can read lowercase/proper case text just fine, thank you.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support arrays, so what do you mean by this? Are you passing a delimited list of strings? Can you string(s) contain other characters other than A-z? You says you're counting the number of vowels and consonants, but you have a scalar function, so how are you returning 2 values here?

Comment: As for the error `WHILE (@ARRAY!=0)` isn't going to work if `@ARRAY` has any non-numerical characters in it. I, however, don't know what that expression is meant to be as both `@COUNTT` and `@COUNTT1` are assigned the value `0` in the prior statements; so if you check their values then the `WHILE` will never be entered, and it looks like it'll loop indefinitely if you assign them a greater than zero value.

Comment: sorry for uppercase I am used to write the code in SQL server using caps lock.
I am passing a list of strings and it can't contain other characters than A-z.
My first task is to count just vowels, but it has to be counting consonants as well so the code should be edited afterwards.
`@COUNTT` and `@COUNTT1` are set initially with 0 because I intend to use them as counters, first will count the vowels, second consonants.
Let me know if  I could write the syntax  as below : 
`declare @position int
set @position=0
While(@position<len(@ARRAY@))` ?

Comment: *"I am passing a list of strings and it can't contain other characters than A-z."* If it's a list of string, but the value can't have characters other than A-z, how do you know where one string end and another begins..? Sample data and expected results will *really* help us help you here. Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: for now when function has to return just vowels:

sample - select dbo.vow_cons('Knowledge is power')
expected output - `6`

Comment: *""I am passing a list of strings and it can't contain other characters than A-z."* and then you state *"select dbo.vow_cons('Knowledge is power') expected output - 6"*... There is white space there... That is a character other than A-z...

Comment: My bad,  it has to contain empty spaces as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what version of SQL Server you are using, I am going to *assume* you are using the latest version, meaning you have access to `TRANSLATE`. Also I'm going to assume you *do* need access to both the number of vowels *and* consonants, so a table-value function seems the better method here. As such, you could do something like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountVowelsAndConsonants (@String varchar(20)) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    SELECT DATALENGTH(@String) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(@String,'aeiou','|||||'),'|','')) AS Vowels, --Pipe is a character that can't be in your string
           DATALENGTH(@String) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(@String,'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz','|||||||||||||||||||||'),'|','')) AS Consonants --Pipe is a character that can't be in your string
GO
```

And then you can use the function like so:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('MAMAMIA'),('Knowledge is power'))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.CountVowelsAndConsonents(V.YourString);
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014
Thanks for reference!

Comment: Then you'll need to make a bunch of nested replaces, @NicolaevMaxim . Though you won't need to replace the characters with a pipe (`|`) and then a zero length string (`''`); you can replace each character directly to a zero length string.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to split the string into its individual letters using a tally table, join that to a table of vowels/consonants and then get your counts.

Here is a working example, you'll have to update/change for your specific needs but should give you an idea on how it works.

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(100)

SET @string = 'Knowledge is power';

--Here we build a table of all the letters setting a flag on which ones are vowels
DECLARE @VowelConsonants TABLE
    (
        [Letter] CHAR(1)
      , [IsVowel] BIT
    );

--We load it with the data
INSERT INTO @VowelConsonants (
                                 [Letter]
                               , [IsVowel]
                             )
VALUES ( 'a', 1 ) , ( 'b', 0 ) , ( 'c', 0 ) , ( 'd', 0 ) , ( 'e', 1 ) , ( 'f', 0 ) , ( 'g', 0 ) , ( 'h', 0 ) , ( 'i', 1 ) , ( 'j', 0 ) , ( 'k', 0 ) , ( 'l', 0 ) , ( 'm', 0 ) , ( 'n', 0 ) , ( 'o', 1 ) , ( 'p', 0 ) , ( 'q', 0 ) , ( 'r', 0 ) , ( 's', 0 ) , ( 't', 0 ) , ( 'u', 1 ) , ( 'v', 0 ) , ( 'w', 0 ) , ( 'x', 0 ) , ( 'y', 0 ) , ( 'z', 0 );

--This tally table example gives 10,000 numbers
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
SELECT     SUM(   CASE WHEN [vc].[IsVowel] = 1 THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                  END
              ) AS [VowelCount]
         , SUM(   CASE WHEN [vc].[IsVowel] = 0 THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                  END
              ) AS [ConsonantCount]
FROM       [cteTally] [t] --Select from tally cte
INNER JOIN @VowelConsonants [vc]  --Join to VowelConsonants table on the letter.
    ON LOWER([vc].[Letter]) = LOWER(SUBSTRING(@string, [t].[N], 1))  --Using the number from the tally table we can easily split out each letter using substring
WHERE      [t].[N] <= LEN(@string);
```

Giving you results of:

```
VowelCount  ConsonantCount
----------- --------------
6           10
```